# Javascript/JQuery Associate Checkbock value with textbox and put in an value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Example code:

```
Present <input type='checkbox' value='student1' id='id_A' name='A' />
Absent <input type='checkbox' value='student1' id='id_B' name='B' />
Comments <input type='text' name='comments' id='id_comments' />

Present <input type='checkbox' value='student2' id='id_A' name='A' />
Absent <input type='checkbox' value='student2' id='id_B' name='B' />
Comments <input type='text' name='comments' id='id_comments' />
```

and so on in a loop for all users, comments field having text is optional.

Issue:
I would like depending lets say for `student1`, if the checkbox field has text, I want to associate the appropriate checkbox value that is checked, in this case if `student1` is present and has text in comments, `'always 10 minutes late'`. I should be able to have probably in a array,

```
PresentArray = {'Student1' : 'always 10 minutes late', 'Student2' : ''}
```

I am new to programming, I prefer to use checkboxes for specific reasons with the users.

Comment: See my updated answer, if i helped you mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I should be able to have probably in a array, 'PresentArray =
>   {'Student1' : 'always 10 minutes late', 'Student2' : ''}'

Your `PersentArray` is not an `array []` but `object {}`.

Keeping your HTML inputs this way is a mistake. You have duplicate `id` attributes which should be unique within `document`.

Also you did not include any code, have you tried anything? Stackoverflow is a place to learn, we are not here to do a homework for you.

I've refactored your HTML. If I understood you correctly you need to check if student is present and has given comment then we can add him to an array. This is what the script does.

Instead of `checkbox` we use `radio` because student can't be present and absent at the same time.

See working example and read my comments carefully to have better understanding. If you have any question be sure to ask.

```js
var students = [];

var formInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

// You can use this function eg. var studentsInfo = populatePresentArray();
// Function returns populated PresentArray []
function populatePresentArray() {
  for (i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = formInputs[i];
  
    // if input is type radio and is checked then we assume
    if (input.value === 'present' && input.checked) {
    
      // query Comment input for current student
      var comment = document.querySelector('input[name="' + input.name + '-comments"]');
    
      // Now let's check if comments has required text
      if (comment.value === 'always 10 minutes late') {
        // All conditions are met, lets add to array new record
        students.push({ [input.name] : comment.value });
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Log it
  console.log(students);
  
  return students;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="studentsForm">
Present <input type="radio" value="present" name="student1" checked />
Absent <input type="radio" value="absent" name="student1" />
Comments <input type="text" name='student1-comments' value="" />
<br>
Present <input type="radio" value="present" name="student2" checked />
Absent <input type="radio" value="absent" name="student2" />
Comments <input type="text" name='student2-comments' value="always 10 minutes late" />
<br>
Present <input type="radio" value="present" name="student3" checked />
Absent <input type="radio" value="absent" name="student3" />
Comments <input type="text" name='student3-comments' value="always 10 minutes late" />
<br>
Present <input type="radio" value="present" name="student4"  />
Absent <input type="radio" value="absent" name="student4" checked />
Comments <input type="text" name='student4-comments' value="always 10 minutes late" />
<br>
Present <input type="radio" value="present" name="student5" checked />
Absent <input type="radio" value="absent" name="student5" />
Comments <input type="text" name='student5-comments' value="" />
<br>
<button onclick="populatePresentArray()" type="button">PresentArray</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks man, works. Can you tell me one more thing..now when the object is passed back to the view, though i can see it as a list...in the view..i want the studentid key and the value, seperate.
Currently, I see this when i do a print: [{"1":"pres"},{"3":"yes pres"}]']. I want to iterate individually and get each key and value.